# Create python dictionary from text using regex to distinguish between specific sections

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a python function to take a chunk of text, parsed from a text file using f.readlines and split this chunk of text into a list. The text contains dividers and I want to split this text specifically at these locations. There are 7 dividers: `["@model", "@units", "@compartments", "@species", "@parameters", "@rules", "@reactions", "@events"]`, please note that '@r' is not a divider but needs to appear under the 'reactions' section.

Here is an example of the text file in question.

```
@model:2.4.0=Skeleton "Skeleton"
@compartments
 Cell=1.0 "Cell"
@species
 Cell:[A]=100.0 "A"
 Cell:[B]=1.0 "B"
 Cell:[C]=0.0 "C"
 Cell:[D]=0.0 "D"
@parameters
kcat=4000
km = 146
v2_k = 88
@reactions
@r=v1 "v1"
 A -> C : B
 Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A) 
@r=v2 "v2"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
```

My desired output is to have a python dictionary that has the name of the dividers as keys and all the content between that divider and the next as values (once again note that anything with '@r' in the beginning of the line is not a divider but should appear under the reactions key. For example, the first element of the sections dictionary should be:

sections['@model']=:2.4.0=Skeleton "Skeleton"

Current Code

```
def split_sections(SBshorthand_file):
    '''
    Takes a SBshorthand file and returns a dictionary of each of the sections. 
    Keys of the dictionary are the dividers.
    Values of dictionary are the content between dividers. 
    '''
    SBfile=parse_SBshorthand_read(SBshorthand_file)
    dividers=["@model", "@units", "@compartments", "@species", "@parameters", "@rules", "@reactions", "@events"]
    sections={}
    for i in  dividers:
        pattern=re.compile(i)
        if re.findall(pattern,SBfile) == []:
            pass
        else:
            sections= dict(re.findall(r"(?:^|(?<=\n))(@\w+)([\s\S]*?)(?=\n@\w+|$)",SBfile))
    return sections
```

This regex almost does what I need. The problem is that it recognizes '@r' as a key and as I explained above, this information needs to appear under the '@reactions' key. Would anybody know how to modify this code to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that expects the input as iterable of lines and uses just one pass over the input, i.e. it may be supplied in a streaming fashion.  And it has less cryptic regular expressions. :-)

```
import re
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

LINES = """\
@model:2.4.0=Skeleton "Skeleton"
@compartments
 Cell=1.0 "Cell"
@species
 Cell:[A]=100.0 "A"
 Cell:[B]=1.0 "B"
 Cell:[C]=0.0 "C"
 Cell:[D]=0.0 "D"
@parameters
kcat=4000
km = 146
v2_k = 88
@reactions
@r=v1 "v1"
 A -> C : B
 Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A) 
@r=v2 "v2"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
""".splitlines(True)

SECTION_RE = re.compile(
    '@(?P<name>model|units|compartments|species|parameters|rules|reactions|events)'
)

def parse_sections(lines):

    result = dict()

    def stamp():
        section = None
        for line in lines:
            match = SECTION_RE.match(line)
            if match:
                section = match.group('name')
            yield (section, line)

    for key, group in groupby(stamp(), itemgetter(0)):
        result[key] = [x for _, x in group]

    return result


def main():
    pprint(parse_sections(LINES))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
{'compartments': ['@compartments\n', ' Cell=1.0 "Cell"\n'],
 'model': ['@model:2.4.0=Skeleton "Skeleton"\n'],
 'parameters': ['@parameters\n', 'kcat=4000\n', 'km = 146\n', 'v2_k = 88\n'],
 'reactions': ['@reactions\n',
               '@r=v1 "v1"\n',
               ' A -> C : B\n',
               ' Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A) \n',
               '@r=v2 "v2"\n',
               ' C -> C+D\n',
               ' Cell * v2_k * C\n'],
 'species': ['@species\n',
             ' Cell:[A]=100.0 "A"\n',
             ' Cell:[B]=1.0 "B"\n',
             ' Cell:[C]=0.0 "C"\n',
             ' Cell:[D]=0.0 "D"\n']}
```

Answer (score 1):

(?:^|(?<=\n))(@\w+)([\s\S]*?)(?=\n[@][^@]\w+|$)